# Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query with operator - OR

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-2013

I know there is 100+ posts about it, but there is a information about time out etc, not about query...
**MySQL Server:** 5.7.17
**MySQL Workbench:** 6.3.8

Query:

```
SELECT transactionID, fromAccount,ToAccount, transactionDate, amount, type 
FROM accounttransactions WHERE toAccount = '12345' #OR fromAccount = '12345'
```

Respond:
It works, but when I change my query and add(uncomment in this scenario) `OR` in `WHERE` statement then it Running for ~6s and looks like:

`Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Comment: What indexes do you have on `accounttransactions`? What does the explain plan look like?

Comment: Indexes in table: PK BTREE - `transactionId`, FK `fromAccount`, FK `toAccount`. There is just about 20 rows, so it should work instantly

Comment: You sure the server does not have a [max_execution_time variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_execution_time) enabled or uses a MySQL proxy that adds [MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(N)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html#optimizer-hints-execution-time) as optimizer hint?

Comment: "so it should work instantly " How do you know? @Slideroh you didn't run `EXPLAIN` a query with `WHERE` clause with `OR` or `AND` keywords needs [multicolumn indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).. But for 20 rows in the table MySQL optimizer will likey not use the indexes.

Comment: EXPLAIN command return the same error (`Lost connection to MySQL server...`) with `OR`

Comment: @RaymondNijland Max_execution_time is not enabled

Comment: Wierd then i think you should reinstall MySQL again i think MySQL is going wierd here.

Comment: Well, to be honest, before I asked you here, I reinstalled the MySQL server. Maybe I should update version? Strange, because recently everything on the same VM works...